# MS Access System Resources exceeded with select query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I saw this question asked a few times here but none i saw seemed to address my specific issue. I have a select query that is pulling from 2 linked tables. When i run the query about 5 min later i get an error saying system resources exceeded. Any idea how i can fix this? Below is my query, The two tables are rather large with 146k rows and 24 columns in one and 312K rows and 67 columns in the other. Is this just too much data for Access?

```
SELECT [Learner Name]=[learning item number] AS [Key],
   Date()                                AS [Business Day],
   [business day] - [updated due date]   AS [Days Overdue],
   Iif([days      overdue] > 0, "true", "false")    AS [Greater Than Zero],
   assignments.[standard id],
   assignments.[learner name],
   [email]                               AS [Email Address],
   active_workforce.employee_status,
   active_workforce.employee_type,
   active_workforce. [bank title desc],
   assignments.[learning item number],
   assignments.[learning item      name],
   assignments.[learning item type],
   assignments.[enrollment record status],
   assignments.[enrollment record substatus],
   assignments.[enrollment type],
   assignments.[enrolled on date],
   assignments.[due date],
   Iif([due date] BETWEEN #3 / 16 / 2020 # AND #7 / 31 / 2020 # ,
   [due date] + 30,
   [due date])                           AS [Update Due Date],
   assignments.[upcoming or overdue],
   assignments.[business unit],
   assignments.department,
   active_workforce.job_code,
   assignments.job,
   assignments. [legal employer],
   assignments.[manager name],
   assignments.[manager sid],
   assignments. [location name],
   assignments.position,
   active_workforce.start_dt,
   active_workforce.cost_ctr_nbr,
   active_workforce.cost_ctr_desc,
   active_workforce.city,
   active_workforce.country_name,
   active_workforce.region_code,
   active_workforce.company,
   active_workforce.level_02_manager_sid,
   active_workforce.level_02_manager,
   active_workforce.level_03_manager_sid,
   active_workforce.level_03_manager,
   active_workforce.level_04_manager_sid,
   active_workforce.level_04_manager,
   active_workforce.level_05_manager_sid,
   active_workforce.level_05_manager,
   active_workforce.level_06_manager_sid,
   active_workforce.level_06_manager,
   active_workforce.level_07_manager_sid,
   active_workforce.level_07_manager,
   active_workforce.level_08_manager_sid,
   active_workforce.level_08_manager,
   active_workforce.level_09_manager_sid,
   active_workforce.level_09_manager,
   active_workforce.level_10_manager_sid,
   active_workforce.level_10_manager,
   active_workforce.[lob code],
   active_workforce.[lob      description],
   active_workforce.[sub lob code],
   active_workforce.[sub lob      description],
   active_workforce.[level 7 code],
   active_workforce.[level 7      description],
   active_workforce.[level 8 code],
   active_workforce.[level 8      description],
   active_workforce.[level 9 code],
   active_workforce.[level 9      description],
   active_workforce.[level 10 code],
   active_workforce.[level 10      description],
   active_workforce.[level 11 code],
   active_workforce.[level 11      description],
   active_workforce.[level 12 code],
   active_workforce.[level 12      description],
   active_workforce.[level 13 code],
   active_workforce.[level 13      description],
   active_workforce.[level 14 code],
   active_workforce.[level 14      description]
FROM   assignments
   INNER JOIN active_workforce
           ON assignments.[standard id] = active_workforce.sid;
```

Comment: Do a Compact & Repair. -- This should give a syntax error: `SELECT [Learner Name]=[learning item number] AS [Key]`

Answer (score 1):

Break this query into several simpler ones, and write temporary tables for the intermediate results of each query.  Recombine the data into a final result using one or more final queries.

---

Actually, this query (once I formatted it for easier reading) doesn't seem all that complicated.  Check to make sure you have indices on each side of the `assignments.[standard id] = active_workforce.sid` inner join.  Without indices, Access might be trying to assemble the whole thing in memory, which sounds like too much given your stated specifications.

Alternatively, put this data into a SQL Server Express database, and let SQL Server handle it.  But you're still going to need indices on `assignments.[standard id]` and `active_workforce.sid`.

Comment: I don't have access to SQL Server unfortunately. I am jumping back into SQL after being out of it for awhile. What do you mean indices on each side?

Comment: Also these are linked tables so i do not believe i can index them. Maybe ill unlink an create a front end to upload

Comment: You can index `[standard id]` and `sid` in the backend (linked) database.

Answer (score 0):

Create the simplest query to select the records:

```sql
SELECT
    assignments.[standard id]
FROM
    assignments
INNER JOIN 
    active_workforce
    ON assignments.[standard id] = active_workforce.sid;
```

Save this and create a new query having the saved query as source and include a *left outer join* to each of the tables to pull the relevant fields from these. Check, that this runs.

Finally, add your expressions.

Comment: Cant even link the one table anymore. I keep getting error "The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or does not exist"

Comment: Double-check - as I guess you haven't deleted the tables ... something else is going on.